# SQL question: How to transform a string/char varibale yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ into date format and calculate difference between 2 dates

Tags: sql, date, format, transform

I have 2 string variables date1 and date2, ex: `2018-11-05T00:00:00.000+01:00`
Now I would like to calculate the difference between these 2 variables in SQL that is not bigger than 60 days

Am I missing something:

```
select abs(datediff(day,(convert(date1(50),getdate(),127)), (convert(date2(50),getdate(),127))))<60
```

Comment: 1st parameter of `CONVERT` function is a datatype the value must be converted into. `date1(50)` and `date2(50)` are not valid datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select some_column
from your_table_name
where abs(datediff(day,(convert(datetime, left(date1, 10), 127))
               , (convert(datetime, left(date2, 10), 127)))) < 60
```

I used left function to select first 10 characters of the string because you need to calculate the day difference. Hope it helps.

Comment: Here is a list of the available optionas for [date and time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) (The 10 in the convert statement)